# iOS CoreLocation plot user location on top of image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, core-location

i'm trying to create a building navigation application similar to http://navigationapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/point-inside-2.png . I'm planning on displaying the building floor plan image as a UIImageView and using CoreLocation to get the longitude and latitude coordinates for the pin pointer. The next step - which im also stuck on, how do i plot the point on the image? - i am already able to retrieve the users lat and lot coordinates ..

Comment: @spike Lee i want to do same thing how can i start will tell me some initial steps to start it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you firstly a UIImageView to display some sort of icon for the pin pointer, and then a function to transform lat/long coordinates into the position on your image.

Assuming your building floor plan image is aligned with north at the top,

```
- (CGPoint)plotPointOfLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(/* the lat/long of the top-left of the plan image */);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(/* the lat/long of the bottom-right of the plan image */);
    CGSize planImageSize = CGSizeMake(/* the size of the plan image, as drawn on the screen, in pixels */);

    CLLocationDegrees latSpan = bottomRightCoordinate.latitude - topLeftCoordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longSpan = bottomRightCoordinate.longitude - topLeftCoordinate.longitude;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D offsetLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude - topLeftCoordinate.latitude,
                                                                       location.longitude - topLeftCoordinate.longitude);

    CGPoint ret = CGPointMake((offsetLocation.latitude / latSpan) * planImageSize.width,
                              (offsetLocation.longitude / longSpan) * planImageSize.height);
    return ret;
}
```

Then just set your pin UIImageView 'center' property to the value returned from this method.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, could u also tell me the image aligning process ? What resolution/size does it need to be ?

Comment: It can be any size/resolution you like, but the size that it is displayed on the screen must be entered into `planImageSize`. Note also that the returned point is relative to the top-left of the image, so you might have to offset this if your image view isn't sitting at 0,0 of its superview.

Comment: Sorry but it gives wrong (x,y) co-ordinates can u suggest something what is wrong